# Сonditional wrapper inside mixin

Tags: pug

```
mixin step(arr)
  each item in arr
    .step__item.col-md.col-sm-6
       .step__icon
          i(class=item.icon)
       .step__text=item.text
```

`arr` is an array of an objects. I want to add conditional wrapper for `.step__item` if specific property is defined in object.
How do I make it without doubling whole code in else statement like this:

```
mixin step(arr)
  each item in arr
    if item.prop !== undefined
      .wrapper
        .step__item.col-md.col-sm-6
          .step__icon
            i(class=item.icon)
          .step__text=item.text
    else
      .step__item.col-md.col-sm-6
        .step__icon
          i(class=item.icon)
        .step__text=item.text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great use-case for another [Pug mixin](https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html#mixin-blocks), which can be called from within your original mixin:

```
mixin wrapper(condition)
  if condition
    .wrapper
      block
  else
    block

mixin step(arr)
  each item in arr
    +wrapper(item.prop !== undefined)
      .step__item.col-md.col-sm-6
        .step__icon
          i(class=item.icon)
        .step__text=item.text
```

The contents of the `wrapper` mixin will be passed to its block statement, and the `.wrapper` element will only be used if whatever condition you pass as the mixin's argument evaluates to `true`.

Comment: any possibility of making inline condition for parent? Something like `!item.prop ? '' : wrapper`?

Comment: No, not without adding an element.

Answer (score 0):

> any possibility of making inline condition for parent? Something like
> `!item.prop ? '' : wrapper?`

You can, but that will add a wrapping div on your else condition also.

```
mixin step(arr)
  each item in arr
    div(class=(item.prop !== undefined ? 'wrapper': ''))
      .step__item.col-md.col-sm-6
        .step__icon
          i(class=item.icon)
        .step__text=item.text
```